# Permission issue on sysfs access from android application ( .java source code )

Tags: android, permissions, selinux, sysfs

Android application in java having permission issues when accessing sysfs entry.

```
try{
 FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("/sys/class/shift_reg/shift_reg/value");
 byte mybyte = 1;
 fos.write(mybyte);
 fos.close();
} catch ( Exception e) {
 Log.d(TAG, "Failed in writing to Shift Register");      <------- I am always getting this exception.
}
```

1) Have tried putting 'setenforce 0'. Does't work. Even though enforce level is permissive.

2) Do I have to access using JNI way: 
( android-app -> jni -> driver )

3) I have set file permission as 0777 for the sysfs node file.

Dmesg Error message:

> [  417.176302] type=1400 audit(418.589:63): avc: denied { write } for
>   pid=3164 comm="com.android.cam" name="value" dev="sysfs" ino=9749
>   scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:sysfs:s0 tclass=file
>   permissive=1

ps -Z

> u:r:untrusted_app:s0           u0_a67    4360  333
>   com.android.cam

Answer (score 0):

Following are some of the options I came across.

**1. Direct access from the application  [ Android Application(.java) -> jni -> driver  ]**
Do I need to implement jni.
[Doubt] Will the jni solution will not have same permission issue as only java application.

*[Ans]This won’t work.*

**2. Signing my application as 'platform_app'.** 
Currently it shows as 'untrusted_app'

*[Ans] Platform app is still in app domain.  This won’t work.*

**3. Using any existing android hardware API.**
Would it possible to reuse something from existing ones( modifying something from existing ones )
       1) android.hardware
       2) android.hardware.input

*[Ans] Yes.  Probably easiest way but be careful not to conflict with other modules that use the HAL you are modifying.*

**4. Adding a new custom system service**
I believe there are 2 options of adding a system service
      1) Adding inside the System Server
      2) Adding outside of the System Server

[Ans]    Yes. One of proper solutions.

**5. Will developing the app using NDK help with permissions**

*[Ans]    An app is still in app domain.  You will not get permissions.*

Note:

System service implementations github:

https://github.com/opersys/opersys-hal-hw